# Google Assistant on Raspberry pi text input speech output

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to use Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi, I'm using text as input and it provides output in text. I was wondering if it was possible to get the output in speech?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the [`AudioOut` data](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.AudioOut) if you're using the service, which would enable you to obtain the raw speech output.

You can check out the [pushtotalk](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py) sample to see how to play audio output.